# How to set DataGridRow Color and alternating row color in WPF?

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, datagrid, datagridrow

How do I set the `DataGridRow` color to the `DataGrid` dependency property `RowBackground`?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="EmployeeDataGridStyle">

  <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightCyan"/>
  ...
</Style>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="EmployeeDataGridRowStyle">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background = { ??? //set this to the datagrid rowbackground }
                >
                ...
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal_AlternatingRow">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                    Duration="0"
                    To="{ ??? // AlternatingRowBackground color that is set in the datagrid
                    >
                    ...
```

I am trying to set the `DataGridRow` color in the template to the `DataGrid` `RowBackgroundColor` property and trying to set the alternating row color using visual states to the `AlternatingRowColor` property of the `DataGrid`. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: The DataGridRow has an AlternationIndex property.
It can be bound to the collection of colors specified in the AlternationConverter.
Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter?view=netcore-3.1

You can also use the ItemsControl.AlternationIndex Attachable Property.
Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Why are you using VisualStateManager?
It is much easier to do this with Triggers.
What type of project do you have WPF Framework, WPF Core, UWP?

Comment: @EldHasp I am using the WPF Core Framework, I heard that VisualStateManager gives you better flexibility and more options to work with rather than triggers, therefore I chose to work with that. The method in the above two links will not allow me to template the values set in the datagrid dependency property right ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this template? The default one handles alternation count and background colour without change. Did you take a look at that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates  If you're changing templates it's always best IMO to start with the original and iterate with small change, check it still works, small change... and so on. Until you get what you want. Everything at once often ends up with something completely irretrievably broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding to `RowBackground` of the `DataGrid` can be done using  a `RelativeSource` binding.

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=RowBackground}"
```

However, the second binding in `ColorAnmination` on the `To` property is impossible [by design.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN#animate-in-a-controltemplate)

> **You can't use dynamic resource references or data binding expressions to set Storyboard or animation property values**. That's because everything inside a ControlTemplate must be thread-safe, and the timing system must FreezeStoryboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource references or data binding expressions. For more information about freezing and other Freezable features, see the [Freezable Objects Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview).

You can bind `AlternatingRowBackground` apart from animations the same way as above.

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=AlternatingRowBackground}"
```

Comment: This will set the background property of the datagridrow template border.background right ? How do I set it so that it refers to the Rowbackground and the AlternatingRowBackground Property defined in the datagrid ?

Comment: @JeffreyChen Adapted my answer, now that I understand your intent.